# Android Studio how to make notifications with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'd like to make notifications with Firebase when the Firebase Database is modified. I guess this could make with Firebase functions and Firebase Cloud Messaging, but I don't know if this way is correct or not, please if someone can help me clarifying this doubt, below I explain that I want my application to do, thx!!

I want my app to send notifications all the users near the another user(1km for example) when this user publish an ad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fellow developers, I encourage you to boldly try whatever comes up in your mind!

But if I were you, I'd do the same thing. Firebase Functions allow you to have function trigger according to Firebase Realtime Database events. So you can use that, to trigger a specific function that will send a FCM Message.

In your Android App, make sure to implement `FirebaseMessagingService` (and set it up in your `AndroidManifest.xml`), and every time message is received (through `FirebaseMessagingService.onMessageReceived`), create new notification!

Comment: Thanks!! :D , and do you know if there is something to get the each user's location to send only the users near the user who has published?

Comment: That one is a little bit tricky. :D There are many ways to achieve this. You can do research and choose which one is good. 

But try this: when you send message, you can write down anything. Let's say you include LatLng of the publisher's location. And then whenever the message is received, your app will parse and check the distance between user's and publisher's location. If it's within 1km, then go ahead and create notification.